# Android permission not asked correctly with version 31

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have a Android app done with Delphi 10.4 (upgraded to 11.2).

I have lot of permission in my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT"/>
```

Then I ask for runtime permissions :

```
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions(
    [JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.CAMERA),
     JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
     JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
     JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_PHONE_STATE),
     JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.RECORD_AUDIO)
    ], ...
```

That's work perfectly, but when I want to publish my app, Play store ask to update my Sdk version to 31 (I replace 29 by targetSdkVersion="31")

I add `exported=true` when necessary and replace :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
// by 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
// and added BLUETOOTH_SCAN + BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE + BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
```

On Android 13, permission are not asked correctly.
The first time I open the app, the application ask me to accept `BLUETOOTH` only and then nothing append, but the app still working and crash when I want use the Camera.

If I close the app and open it, then my application ask me for the others permissions (Camera, Read/Write, ..)

I try to put Bluetooth at the end of the file, but I got same problem.

If I use `targetSdkVersion="29"` as before, it's ok.

Based on the documentation I dont see what to do : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android12-or-higher

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem on Android 13.
App dont ask user for permissions.

On Android 12 work fine.

App Try ask:

     'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
     'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
     'android.permission.READ_CONTACTS';

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. I had to move the code of asking for the permissions to different places. So when the application starts, I ask for Bluetooth permissions only. Before using the storage, I added to code to ask for the storage permission. Before using the camera, I did the same.